TV show about the struggles of a teenage mother
I'm looking for the name of a show that I can't remember. I don't remember the release year, probably around 2012 or something like that? The language is English and I remember bits and parts of the TV show but not much.
From what I remember in the show, a guy gets a girl pregnant during summer camp, and she shows us the memories. Then later on she gives birth, the kid's name is John. After a few shows the parents of John are fighting and John puts his hands over his ears. The mom thinks that he's sick while the dad thinks that he's fine. The girl is 17, I think. By the way, the guy looks a lot like Rahart Adams (Jax Novoa from Every Witch Way if you watch that show).

Welcome to Movies&TV. Do you remember release year, language, country or other plot details, any at all? Add them so that it can help identify this movie. Also see How to ask Identify-this-X questions.

You might also want to provide a more descriptive question title.

The Secret Life of the American Teenager

After an unplanned pregnancy, teenager Amy Juergens's life will never be the same, as she deals with other teenagers around her.

and she got pregnant at a band camp and named her child John.




THE SECRET LIFE OF THE AMERICAN TEENAGER! YES THIS IS IT! THANK YOU DO MUCH!

@WolfLover123 Please accept this answer if it is the correct solution to your problem.
